# How to get list of "Security Group - Global" and its members in PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I am able to pull out hte list of Users and Organization units from LDAP. But I need to also list the **Security Group - Global** and the member name under this group.

[image]

I use this following code to pull the users.

ldap_search($mydap,'ou=abc users,dc=corp,dc=abc,dc=ca','cn=*',array('member')) or die('Error searching LDAP: '.ldap_error($mydap));

How to code to pull the list from **Security Group - Global**?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, a [search filter similar](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-AllSecurityGroupsWithAGroupTypeOfGlobal) to:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483650))
```

Should do the trick.